# How can I count number of times the specific word occured in database?

Tags: java, sql

I want to count the number of times the specific word occurs in a database using java?

For example, my database c-ram contains

```
Words
=====

john smith john,
mary jones,
mary john albert
```

[Words is the field name in c-ram table]

I want to check how many times "john" occurred in c-ram.

I have checked coding without query too, but I cant find the solution. If I use this below query I get same query as output, also I can't use integer variable to assign for this query.

```
for(int jm=0;jm<ij;jm++)
{ 
    String query1 = null;
    for(int k=0;k<ikm;k++)
    {
        if(word[jm].contains(item1))
        {
            query1="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c_ram WHERE Words = item";
        }
```

help me to get answer with or without using query.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of Java Pattern matching. Sample code is this

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("john");
    int count=0;
    String sql = "SELECT words FROM c_ram";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet result=statement.executeQuery(sql);
    while(result.next()) {
      Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(result.getString(1));
      while(matcher.find())
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thanks Pulkit. but In this work, [ john smith john, mary jones, mary john albert] where stored in c -ram table. so i have to check how many times the john occured in that table.

Comment: So you want to check in particular column say Column1 you want to check how may times a word ocxured in whole table?

Comment: c-ram contains only one column named as "Words". in that Words i wanna check how many times  john is ocuured [ john smith john, mary jones, mary john albert]. here john occur 3 times. so i want this output

Comment: Well in that case you need to fetch the whole column and iterate over the list, I must warn you it is a heavy operation, Let me update my answer

Comment: thanks for ur concern pulkit. but this is the my available code. i can't change it. but please tel me how it is a heavy operation

Comment: the reason why its a a heavy operation is 1) You are fetching the whole column from db. 2) Pattern matching is itself heavy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97534/discussion-between-deepa-13-and-pulkit).